# Customizing Nested Tabs (HTML/CSS)

Tags: html, css, tabs

Right now at my job, I'm tasked with creating a monitoring dashboard site. I'm thoroughly looking through a lot of different design choices and what my company wants, but all the templates I'm looking at for dashboards aren't formatted the way the company wants: a nested tab feature, not a side bar navigation.

Upon looking through a bunch of nested tab examples, one of them caught my attention which was [Zozoui's Nested Tabs](http://zozoui.com/tabs/nested/). This isn't something I've seen from BootStrap and JQuery UI, so I don't even know how to begin with starting something like this, but I'd like to change a couple of things here and there, like right before the second set of tabs, have a description of the first current tag.

So in short, how do I create my own nested tab feature like [Zozoui's Nested Tabs](http://zozoui.com/tabs/nested/)?

Comment: Bootstrap has that kinda tabs, you can create it very easy. What's so special at those Zozo tabs? Maybe I am missing something

Comment: Zozo's tab has this very simple and a very minimalist look to the tabs. In fact they're just text with some animation to it. The problem is, how do I format my words like that into a navigation pane?

Comment: you want it only in (pure html and css)?

Comment: I know that the animation will be done in Javascript, but it can be in any language really. I just want to know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a menu and a div for contents when you click a specific tab it's contents should show in that div.do it by jquery or js.

**HTML**

```
<nav id="menu">
<a id="item1">item1</a>
<a id="item2">item2</a>
.
.
.
</nav>

<div id="contents">

<div>
```

**jquery**

```
 $("#menu a").click(function{
     $("contents").html(//something that you want);

    });
```